# Switched from g++ to clang++; now, exceptions thrown in std::ifstream object upon opening file. try/catch exception doesn't work? ( C++ )

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, clang, ifstream

I've recently switched to clang++ as my compiler for just this project since my code actually generated a bug in g++ (seg fault). In my project, I need to do some simple file I/O. The following part of my project is now giving me issues; this compiled and ran fine in g++:

```
std::ifstream m_data_in;
m_data_in.open(filename, std::ios_base::in);
```

With clang, the above code compiles but the executable "stops working" on the 2nd line above. I would like to be able to show a stack trace but gdb can't find clang++'s compiled programs (I had this working fine with g++) don't work with gdb. However, i do have the outputs from the few modifications of the code.

```
std::cout << "hi";
std::ifstream m_data_in;
std::cout << "hi";
m_data_in.open(filename, std::ios_base::in);//, std::ios_base::in);
std::cout << "hi";
```

results in the output:

```
hihi
```

with the "stops working" dialog message popping up. I've also run the following to check if there is perhaps an exception being thrown:

```
std::ifstream m_data_in;
std::string new_line {};

m_data_in.exceptions( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
try 
{
    m_data_in.open(filename, std::ios_base::in);//, std::ios_base::in);
    while ( !m_data_in.eof() ) new_line += m_data_in.get();
}
catch (std::ios_base::failure e )
{
    std::cout << "Exceptions opening/reading file\n";
}
```

from which i get no console output. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: got the gdb backtrace working!

```
(gdb) run main
Starting program: D:\Dropbox\Projects\active\kaggle Higgs Boson/main.exe main
[New Thread 6212.0x428]
training.csvhitraining.csv
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x6fcc43c3 in libstdc++-6!_ZSt4cout () from c:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x6fcc43c3 in libstdc++-6!_ZSt4cout () from c:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#1  0xc81ab000 in ?? ()
#2  0xcc43c06f in ?? ()
#3  0x4172b86f in ?? ()
#4  0x00000c00 in ?? ()
#5  0xcc43c000 in ?? ()
#6  0x28fd206f in ?? ()
#7  0x28fd2000 in ?? ()
#8  0x28fd4000 in ?? ()
#9  0x401e9a00 in ?? ()
#10 0xcc43c000 in ?? ()
#11 0x4043a06f in ?? ()
#12 0x28fd2000 in ?? ()
#13 0x5cf32b00 in ?? ()
#14 0x00000077 in ?? ()
#15 0x76000000 in ?? ()
#16 0x7619a000 in ?? ()
#17 0x5457ce00 in ?? ()
#18 0x523cd377 in ?? ()
#19 0x00000077 in ?? ()
#20 0x00002600 in ?? ()
#21 0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

EDIT 2: Fixed the catch variable from type 'int' to 'std::ios_base::failure'. Still nothing prints from the catch scope.

Comment: What is `filename`? How do you know it's valid? Why are you printing `hi` insread of your program's real data such as `filename`? If your `gdb` cannot debug your `clang` compiled program, why won't you ask for help? Do you know that the "stops working" dialog has nothing to do with C++ exceptions (it signals a crash, not an exception thrown)?

Comment: `filename` is "training.csv". I printed it out to be sure. Also, it successfully loaded `filename` when I was using gcc (the gcc internal seg fault error came later). 

"If your gdb cannot debug your clang compiled program, why won't you ask for help?" it seemed like something I could Google, so i didn't ask that here.

"Do you know that the "stops working" dialog has nothing to do with C++ exceptions (it signals a crash, not an exception thrown)?" - I was aware they weren't necessarily the same ). I was running out of ideas though, and now i'm fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Your test does not look right:  instead of trying to catch an integer, you should catch `std::ios_base::failure` by const reference.  That is thrown after you configured the stream by calling [`exceptions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions)

Comment: ^ Thanks. fixed*. I still don't see the exception error print statement though.

Comment: The `const &` part is still missing. You can also try to catch everything `(...)` and see if something prints then.

Comment: do you compile with `-g3 -O0`?

Comment: Tried catching everything and I still don't get a printed error statement. Here is my entire clang++ command: `clang++ main.cpp -o main.exe -g -g3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -save-temps -I"D:\Dropbox\Projects\include" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\lib" -lstdc++`, including the `-g3 -O0` commands (although maybe I shouldn't keep these flags?).